# Oracle PLSQL Calculate formula by id values

Tags: oracle, plsql, eval, formula

I saw similar posts but didn't help for my problem;

I have a formula reference table like;

```
ID        CODE       FORMULA
1         A          
2         B
3         C          1+2
4         D  
5         E          1+2-4
```

and a value table like;

```
CODE    VALUE
A       100
B       200
D       300
```

and I am trying to calculate a table like this;

```
CODE    VALUE
A       100
B       200
C       300
D       300
E       0
```

Any hint would be much much appreciated.

Actually I solved it with some rexgexp_replace but it worked soooo slow.
Thank you.

Comment: Could you explain the logic?

Comment: At the very least, you should be able to parse the formula from PL/SQL and then build a dynamic query accordingly. This is probably far from being trivial (esp. is you need to support operator precedence or function call). Or are you only limited to `+` and `-` ?

Comment: You can substitute reference number(ids?) with real values assigned to them using regexp_replace. Then given expression execute using dynamic sql.

Comment: The logic is I need to substitute reference id's with real values as @Rusty said, somehow but I couldn't do it. And I couldn't find anything similar array_replace() like in php. I am not limited by + and -

Answer (score 0):

I write some solution which covers Your example and it can be extended to do more, adding new operators and implementing some exception handling, etc. You can kindly have a look at the [Tom Kyte's answers on the evaluating the expressions](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1179235402134) . Also, if it is necessary, You can adopt this solution to be used in the sql itself using the [User-Defined aggregate function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28425/aggr_functions.htm).

```
declare   
   T_ValList dbms_sql.Number_Table;
   T_CalcList dbms_sql.Varchar2_Table;
   li_idx binary_integer;
   -- Converting input to be used in dynamic sql. For example for the input 1+2, we will get p1+:p2
   function v_getBindVars(av_ValueList varchar2) return varchar2 is
   begin   
      return ':p' || replace(replace(replace(av_ValueList, ' '), '+', '+:p'), '-', '-:p');
   end;
   -- Parsing expression to change the values from the correspoinding id's
   function v_getValues(av_ValueList varchar2) return varchar2 is
      lv_string       varchar2(32767) := replace(replace(replace(av_ValueList, ' '), '+', ','), '-', ',') || ',';
      li_comma_index  pls_integer;
      li_index        pls_integer := 1;
      lv_Values       varchar(32767);
   begin
      loop
       li_comma_index := INSTR(lv_string, ',', li_index);
       exit when li_comma_index = 0;
       lv_Values := lv_values || T_ValList(To_Number(SubStr(lv_string, li_index, li_comma_index - li_index))) || ',';
       li_index := li_comma_index + 1;
     end loop;     
     return rtrim(lv_Values, ',');
   end;
   -- Calculates the expression using dymamic SQL
   function n_CalcExpression(av_OperString varchar2) return number is
      ln_result number;
   begin
      execute immediate '
      begin execute immediate ''select ' || v_getBindVars(av_OperString) || ' from dual'' into :ln_res using ' || v_getValues(av_OperString) || '; end;' using out ln_result;
      return ln_result;      
   end;
begin
   -- Separating the values, which need to be calculate and the one's which need to be used
   for F in (with formula as (select 1 id, 'A' Code, '' formula from dual union all
                               select 2, 'B', '' from dual union all
                               select 3, 'C', '1+2' from dual union all
                               select 4, 'D', ''  from dual union all
                               select 5, 'E', '1+2-4' from dual),
                            value as (select 'A' CODE, 100 value from dual union all
                                      select 'B', 200 from dual union all
                                      select 'D', 300 from dual)
                            select f.Id, f.Code, f.Formula, coalesce(v.value, 0) Value
                              from formula f, value v
                             where f.code = v.code(+)
                            order by id) loop
      if F.Formula is null then
         T_ValList(F.Id) := F.Value;
      else
         T_CalcList(F.id) := F.Formula;
      end if;
   end loop;
   -- Calculating the expressions
   li_idx := T_CalcList.first;
   while li_idx is not null loop      
      T_ValList(li_idx) := n_CalcExpression(T_CalcList(li_idx));
      li_idx := T_CalcList.next(li_idx);     
   end loop;   
   -- Outputing the results
   li_idx := T_ValList.first;
   while li_idx is not null loop      
      dbms_output.put_line(T_ValList(li_idx));     
      li_idx := T_ValList.next(li_idx);     
   end loop;   
end;
```

Hope this will help You.